# mutate: chose all rows except the current one in a grouped df (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to flag following overlaps: players with overlapping recovering time intervals in the same team.

here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


# data
df<- data.frame(times=c("01/01/2020","01/02/2020","01/07/2020","01/10/2020","01/01/2020","01/03/2020","01/05/2020","01/07/2020"))
starttime= mdy(df$times)


df <- tibble(team=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
             player=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
             starttime= starttime,
             stoptime= starttime+days(1))


# find overlaps
df %>% 
  mutate(interval=lubridate::interval(starttime,stoptime)) %>% #calculate interval
  group_by(team) %>% 
  mutate(overlap_flag= case_when(
    sum(starttime %within% as.list(interval)) == 0 ~ 0, # I want to chose as.list(interval[except actual row])
    sum(starttime %within% as.list(interval)) > 0 ~ 1, # I want to chose as.list(interval[except actual row])
    TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

gives me:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   team [2]
  team  player starttime  stoptime   interval                       overlap_flag
  <chr>  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <Interval>                            <dbl>
1 A          1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-01 UTC--2020-01-02 UTC            1
2 A          2 2020-01-02 2020-01-03 2020-01-02 UTC--2020-01-03 UTC            1
3 A          3 2020-01-07 2020-01-08 2020-01-07 UTC--2020-01-08 UTC            1
4 A          4 2020-01-10 2020-01-11 2020-01-10 UTC--2020-01-11 UTC            1
5 B          1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-01 UTC--2020-01-02 UTC            1
6 B          2 2020-01-03 2020-01-04 2020-01-03 UTC--2020-01-04 UTC            1
7 B          3 2020-01-05 2020-01-06 2020-01-05 UTC--2020-01-06 UTC            1
8 B          4 2020-01-07 2020-01-08 2020-01-07 UTC--2020-01-08 UTC            1
```

what I want to have is:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   team [2]
  team  player starttime  stoptime   interval                       overlap_flag
  <chr>  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <Interval>                            <dbl>
1 A          1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-01 UTC--2020-01-02 UTC            1
2 A          2 2020-01-02 2020-01-03 2020-01-02 UTC--2020-01-03 UTC            1
3 A          3 2020-01-07 2020-01-08 2020-01-07 UTC--2020-01-08 UTC            0
4 A          4 2020-01-10 2020-01-11 2020-01-10 UTC--2020-01-11 UTC            0
5 B          1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-01 UTC--2020-01-02 UTC            0
6 B          2 2020-01-03 2020-01-04 2020-01-03 UTC--2020-01-04 UTC            0
7 B          3 2020-01-05 2020-01-06 2020-01-05 UTC--2020-01-06 UTC            0
8 B          4 2020-01-07 2020-01-08 2020-01-07 UTC--2020-01-08 UTC            0
```

I know that there might be a `data.table` solution... however, I wonder if this can easily be done with `dplyr`

Comment: sry I think i missed to add the `lubridate` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `row_number()` to loop over the rows and then use that as index in removing the 'starttime' value

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(interval = as.list(interval(starttime, stoptime))) %>% 
  group_by(team) %>%
  mutate(overlap_flag = +(map2_lgl(row_number(), 
        interval, ~ sum(starttime[-.x] %within% .y) > 0)))
```

Comment: Thank you. The second row gets a overlap_flag=0 with this code

Comment: @captcoma It is based on your condition

Comment: that is true, my condition and the wanted df disagreed

Comment: just for my understanding, what does the `+` and `[-.x]` exactly do/mean?

Comment: @captcoma the `-` is to select all other values except that i.e. `v1 <- c(4, 3, 2); v1[-1]`. In essence, it is selecting all values except that value corresponding to the index.. Similarly, the `+` is to coerce the logical output from `map2_lgl` to binary It can be also done with `as.integer`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if you can exclude one row directly however, here is one way usign `purrr`'s `map` function. Also looking at your expected output it seems you also want to consider `stoptime` to determine  `overlap_flag`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(interval=interval(starttime,stoptime)) %>%
  group_by(team) %>% 
  mutate(overlap_flag = purrr::map_int(row_number(),
 ~+any(starttime[.x] %within% interval[-.x] | stoptime[.x] %within% interval[-.x])))


#  team  player starttime  stoptime   interval                       overlap_flag
#  <chr>  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <Interval>                            <int>
#1 A          1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-01 UTC--2020-01-02 UTC            1
#2 A          2 2020-01-02 2020-01-03 2020-01-02 UTC--2020-01-03 UTC            1
#3 A          3 2020-01-07 2020-01-08 2020-01-07 UTC--2020-01-08 UTC            0
#4 A          4 2020-01-10 2020-01-11 2020-01-10 UTC--2020-01-11 UTC            0
#5 B          1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-01 UTC--2020-01-02 UTC            0
#6 B          2 2020-01-03 2020-01-04 2020-01-03 UTC--2020-01-04 UTC            0
#7 B          3 2020-01-05 2020-01-06 2020-01-05 UTC--2020-01-06 UTC            0
#8 B          4 2020-01-07 2020-01-08 2020-01-07 UTC--2020-01-08 UTC            0
```

Comment: @akrun Not exactly. The framework is the same but logic which I am using is completely different than yours. You'll be able to find the difference in the code by comparing the output from both of our codes.

Comment: upvote for noticing the disagreement between the condition and the wanted df I gave